# How to Upload an image to the API server with a String

Tags: java, android, api

I'm working on an android project that require me to upload an image file and a String to the API server, but I've got stuck, because I used to use StringRequest and JsonObjectRequest. However, this two ways don't accept the two types of parameters. Could anyone help me with this problem? I've tried the Retrofit, but it really doesn't work with that, because I don't really understand the concept of the Retrofit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `How to Upload an image to the API server with a String ` With? I think with a base64 string would do. Ohhh... you mean AND!

Comment: Yes, my API needs two parameters, one is a String type like a token or id of the user, and another one is an image file, like jpg jpeg or png. I have tried the base 64 string too, but it seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: The subject of your post is still confusing. I did my best to tell you why it was confusing.

Comment: I want to express my title that I need help for uploading an image to the API server, that the server needs two parameters, with a String here means another parameter is a String type.

Comment: Do you really not understand what is so confusing on your title? I did my best to explain it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand.